# Inno Setup: Application won't start

Tags: visual-studio, crash, inno-setup

I have a Visual Studio program that I made an installer for using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). I then had a few errors when trying to open the application such as missing .dll's which I added to the project directory. I then got an error like "procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library PvBuffer.dll" which I fixed by adding PvBuffer.dll to the project directory.

Now when I make the installer and try to run the installed application, nothing happens. I click on the application and the program simply crashes. No errors, nothing. The release .exe file works fine in the project but the installed application doesn't. Any suggestions of what might be causing this? Thanks

**Edit 1:** Slappy here is my installer script:

```
[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{AFC14F65-6DD7-479B-AA27-C15F14763641}
AppName=FLIR615
AppVersion=1.5
;AppVerName=FLIR615 1.5
AppPublisher=My Company, Inc.
AppPublisherURL=http://www.example.com/
AppSupportURL=http://www.example.com/
AppUpdatesURL=http://www.example.com/
DefaultDirName={pf}\FLIR615
DefaultGroupName=FLIR615
AllowNoIcons=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]
Source: "D:\FLIR Project\FLIR Project\GEVPlayerSample\SampleRelease\GEVPlayerSample.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\FLIR Project\FLIR Project\GEVPlayerSample\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\FLIR615"; Filename: "{app}\GEVPlayerSample.exe"
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,FLIR615}"; Filename: "http://www.example.com/"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,FLIR615}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\FLIR615"; Filename: "{app}\GEVPlayerSample.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\FLIR615"; Filename: "{app}\GEVPlayerSample.exe"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\GEVPlayerSample.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,FLIR615}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

**Edit 2** KirbyFan64SOS Here is what the errors are in dependency walker:

[image]

**Edit 3** After monitoring the crash in event viewer I noticed some errors which I have posted below

[image]

The errors that are the linked to the program that crashed seem to relate to KERNALBASE.dll. Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: If you run the program from the command prompt and then enter `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`, what is the output?

Comment: Can you paste your installer script?

Comment: @Slappy I have added my installer script

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos the error level is 0. One thing I did notice is when I opened the installed program's directory it still had the visual studio project files in the folder. Is it supposed to have that?

Comment: Also I discovered that there are certain .dll's that the program needs in order to run otherwise it gets an error, but when the .dll's are in the same directory as the .exe file that's when the program doesn't work

Comment: @oodan123 So, when you run it from the command line, it doesn't print any errors? Could you try running Dependency Walker on it? It's definitely not crashing, because the error code is 0...there is a reason I don't often use Windows anymore. ;)

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos I have added the results of dependency walker :)

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos I made a discovery which I think might be the problem when I monitored the crash in event viewer. Do you have any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: @oodan123 Ack...that's a Windows bug! A quick Google for `kernelbase.dll fault` shows lots of results! The most common issue seems to be a corrupted user profile...try opening a command prompt as administrator, running `sfc /scannow`, and rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the cause for it is not having dll. Right dll (along with 32/64 bit) and exact version is very important.